# How to calculate $E^{T_N}(L(T_i, T_{i+1}))$?

Tags: option-pricing, convexity

suppose $L(T_i, T_{i+1})$ is the LIBOR rate between $T_i$ and $T_{i+1}$, and $T_N$ is some time later than $T_{i+1}$. $E^{T_N}$ is the $T_N$-forward measure.

I tried to work this out using John Hull's timing adjustment methods (ch 29.2 of "Options, futures and other derivatives"), but to no avail.

Could you pls throw some lights here?

Comment: The technique is now standard. See the interest rate book by Brigo.

Comment: @Gordon are you referring to Ch13.8 The Convexity Adjustment and Applications to CMS . . . . . . . pp 559?

Comment: See Proposition 6.3.1 on Page 258 of the second edition. For implementation, certain approximation is needed, for example, to frozen the drift.

Comment: @Gordon thank you. After read Ch 6 till $\S 6.3$, I think the third case ($i>k, t \le T_{k-1}$) of this proposition can solve the problem. May I ask what's the next step? Assume the calibration is done (I guess it's discussed in $\S 6.4$), is the next step Monte Carlo as pp 261 said?-- "discretize equations (6.14) between 0 and t with a sufficiently (but not too) small time step Δt, and generate the distributionally-known Gaussian shocks Zt+Δt − Zt."

Comment: @Gordon May I ask which chapter of Brigo's book is this referring to? "For implementation, certain approximation is needed, for example, to frozen the drift."

Comment: See Section 6.13 for clues, in particular, Page 272.

Comment: @Gordon thanks Gordon, now I understand the tool.

Comment: @Gordon Could you pls comment on "Linear Swap Rate Model"? It seems originate from Philip Hunt and Joanne Kennedy, in their "Financial Derivative in Theory and Practice". I read Antoon Pelsser's "Efficient Methods for Valuing Interest Rate Derivatives" Ch 11.6, used in Ch 11.3.1 to price LIBOR in arrears, and according to Ch 11.1.2, seems also could be used to price other derivatives, for example, the one i'm working on, that all the floating leg LIBOR rates are observed but only paid at the end of the IRS.

Answer (score 1):

well you need to specify dynamics for the rates between 
$$T_{i+1}$$ and $T_N.$ If you make them log-normal then the standard BGM/LMM drift computation applies and you get a state dependent drift.

The expectation does not exist in closed form however.

(See eg More Mathematical Finance for detailed discussion.)

Comment: @Joshi thanks for the recommendation. May I ask which chapter is the result in?